# Como formatar data no formato UTC para yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

Estou trabalhando com o XML de uma NF-e onde os campos de data estão no formato UTC (AAAA-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD) e preciso inseri-las no banco no formato yyyy-mm-dd.

Estou utilizando o SimpleDateFormat para tentar fazer a conversão, mas recebo uma `ParseException` com a mensagem "Unparseable date". Meu código esta assim:

```
public Date getDataEvento() {
    DateFormat dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        return dt.parse(this.dataEvento);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.dataEvento` está chegando em forma de string? `Unparseable` significa que o formato que você está passando não bate com o da string que deseja converter em tipo Date.

Comment: Exato. A string esta da seguinte forma: "2017-09-01T12:13:20-03:00"

Comment: Dá uma olhada nas perguntas que marquei, a segunda provavelmente responde sua duvida.

Comment: Não sei o porque, mas quando removi o "T" funcionou. Fiz assim this.dataEvento.replaceAll("T", " ")

Comment: Funcionou porque seu `SimpleDateFormat` usa `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`. Se você usasse `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`, funcionaria com o "T". Outro detalhe é que é melhor usar `HH` ao invés de `hh`, pois o h minúsculo significa "hour of am/pm" (valores entre 1 e 12, e comportamento "incerto" com valores maiores que 12, já que não tem o am/pm para resolver o valor correto). Já o H maiúsculo trabalha com valores entre 0 e 23, e funciona melhor no seu caso.

Comment: Outro detalhe é que do jeito que está, o offset (`-03:00`) está sendo ignorado e você pode acabar com uma data em outro fuso horário, caso o timezone default da JVM não seja um que usa `-03:00`. Então na verdade o `SimpleDateFormat` deveria usar `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` - o `X` funciona no Java >= 7